# SSL Pinning React Native

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove SSL pinning with Android device.

I've tried different techniques like hooking the app with Objection, re-pinning with Frida, using the SSLUnpinning app from the Xposed repo, etc. but nothing seemed to work.

The library used is React (RNPinningSsl), below the decription:
https://github.com/nlt2390/react-native-pinning-ssl/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/RNPinningSsl.java

The only thing left for me to do is write a custom javascript and start it with frida. Unfortunately I'm not very good at this and I wanted to ask if you can help me do it.

Thank you very much to anyone who will help me.